# Insert NA in specific row/column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to place NA's in certain row/column positions.

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), 
                  index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
                  columns=['one', 'two', 'three'])

rows = pd.Series([True, False, False, False, True], index = df_test.index)
```

I want to add in the NA's for the rows specified and without column 'two'. I tried this:

```
df_test[rows].drop(['two'], axis = 1) = np.nan
```

But this returns error:

> SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not going to work, Python simply does not support this kind of syntax, i.e., assigning to function calls. Furthermore, `drop` returns a copy, so dropping the column and operating on the returned DataFrame does not modify the original.

Below are a couple of alternatives you may work with.

## `loc` + `pd.Index.difference`

Here, you'll want `loc` based assignment:

```
df_test.loc[rows, df_test.columns.difference(['two'])] = np.nan
df_test

        one       two     three
a       NaN  0.205799       NaN
b  0.296389 -0.508247  0.026844
c  0.970879 -0.549491 -0.056991
d -1.474168 -1.694579  1.493165
e       NaN -0.159641       NaN
```

`loc` works in-place, modifying the original DataFrame as you want. You can also replace `df_test.columns.difference(['two'])` with `['one', 'three']` if you so please.

---

## `df.set_value`

For older pandas versions, you can use `df.set_value` (not in-place)—

```
df_test.set_value(df_test.index[rows], df_test.columns.difference(['two']), np.nan)
        one       two     three
a       NaN  1.562233       NaN
b -0.755127 -0.862368 -0.850386
c -0.193353 -0.033097  1.005041
d -1.679028  1.006895 -0.206164
e       NaN -1.376300       NaN
```

Comment: Thank you. Why does that work but my method did not?

Comment: @jchaykow Well, the answer to that is as simple as "python does not support that kind if syntax (i.e., calling functions and assigning values to them)".